# How to increase String input for every time component method is called

Tags: java, string, composite

I just started learning coding (mainly Java) for about 6 months at a University and now we just covered section of Composite design pattern (with Component, Leaf and Composite classes).

My class problem requires I use the below Component Interface to make a simple director program that I can create/add/remove files/directory.

```java
public interface Component {
    public String getName();
    public int getSize();
    public int getCount();
    public String display(String prefix);
    public Component search(String name);
}
```

Below is the File class that I wrote to be used as Leaf

```java
public class File implements Component { 
    private String name;
    private int size;
    public File(String name, int size){
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String display(String prefix) {
        return this.name + " " + "(" + this.size + ")" + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Component search(String name) {
        if(this.name.equals(name)){
            return this;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Below is the Component Class - Directory Class. I put line of * above the method display in question.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Directory implements Component {
    static int count = 0;
    private String name;
    //Array List to store the leafs
    public ArrayList<Component> children;

    public Directory(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //Method to add leaf to Directory
    public void add(Component component){
        children.add(component);
    }

    //Method to remove leaf from Directory
    public void remove(Component component){
        children.remove(component);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        int size = 0;
        for(Component component : children) {
            size += component.getSize();
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = 0;
        for(Component component : children) {
            count += component.getCount();
        }
        return count;
    }

//***********************************
    @Override
    public String display(String prefix) {
        String totalString = name + ": (count=" + getCount() + ", size=" + getSize() + ")" + System.lineSeparator();

        for (Component component : children) {
            totalString = totalString + prefix + component.display(prefix + prefix);
        }
        return totalString;
    }

//*************************************
    @Override
    public Component search(String name) {
        for(Component component: children) {
            if (component.search(name) != null) {
                return component;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My goal is, when I apply the display method, every-time the component has children, the prefix in display method should increase by 1. To clarify, below is my test method

```java
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File holiday = new File("family-holiday",201);
        File wallpaper = new File("wallpaper", 421);
        Directory pictures = new Directory("pictures");
        Directory personal = new Directory("personal");
        Directory misc = new Directory("misc");
        Directory dog = new Directory("dog");
        dog.add(wallpaper);
        personal.add(holiday);
        personal.add(misc);
        pictures.add(personal);
        misc.add(dog);

        System.out.print(pictures.display("+"));
    }
}
```

The result of this should be

```
pictures: (count=2, size=622)
\+personal: (count=2, size=622)
\++family-holiday (201)
\++misc: (count=1, size=421)
\+++dog: (count=1, size=421)
\++++wallpaper (421)
```

However, due to the display method when component has children, it calls (prefix + prefix) which works until the 3rd directory/files, the prefix gets doubled every time instead of an increment of one. Below is the result I got

```
pictures: (count=2, size=622)
\+personal: (count=2, size=622)
\++family-holiday (201)
\++misc: (count=1, size=421)
\++++dog: (count=1, size=421)
\++++++++wallpaper (421)
```

I have tried multiple ways that I can think of below

- Add prefix at the File display : This obviously did not work if there is director inside directory
- Use static parameter to count number of method getting called, since the number of times prefix should be used depends on how many level the file / director is in there, that doesn't work with full count of the number of times used by the method.
- Adding prefix at MANY MANY different places .. :) Still did not work well. I can imagine it has to be the way I pass the prefix to when the loop is calling display again, but I can't figure out what it is ...

If you could please advise or guide on what I can do or what I should read on to help with this, that will be very helpful. I do apologise in advance if there is similar topics as I couldn't find them with my current knowledge of the keyword, if you could please guide me there then I'm very grateful

Comment: You can see why, right?  When you have `prefix`='++', you then pass `prefix+prefix`, or `++++`.  It would be a better plan to pass "depth" as an integer to describe how deep you are, then construct the prefix by repeating the '+' that many times.  Then you just pass `depth+1`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the feedback. Indeed I understand that prefix + prefix is not the best method .. just the only one I can think of ! 
Since the purpose of this exercise is to implement the given interface (Fix by the problem), I don't think I can change the display method that was specified to have additional input ? If possible, that will definitely help solve the problem.
Please let me know if you have any other thought! Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: I told you how to do it.  Don't pass the prefix string, pass the current depth.   Have your "display" function accept a `int depth`.  Now, it can construct the prefix string by repeating the '+' that many times.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, just pass the depth as an integer and construct the prefix within the display function.

```
    @Override
    public String display(int depth) {
        String prefix = '+'.repeat(depth);
        String totalString = name + ": (count=" + getCount() + ", size=" + getSize() + ")" + System.lineSeparator();

        for (Component component : children) {
            totalString = totalString + prefix + component.display(depth + 1);
        }
        return totalString;
    }

...

        System.out.print(pictures.display(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues in your code but won't address all of them here as this is not https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

But *important*: don't concatenate `String` in a loop with the `+` or `+=` operators. Use `java.lang.StringBuilder` for this.

Instead of doubling your `prefix`, you can calculate the new prefix from the first char and the size of the input prefix. Here is just the `Directory.display` method:

```java
@Override
public String display(String prefix) {
  StringBuilder totalString = new StringBuilder(name);
  totalString.append(": (count=").append(getCount());
  totalString.append(", size=").append(getSize()).append(")");
  totalString.append(System.lineSeparator());

  for (Component component : children) {
    totalString.append(prefix).append(component.display(prefix.substring(0, 1).repeat(prefix.length() + 1)));
  }
  return totalString.toString();
}
```

This way you can keep your given interface exactly as before. Still @TimRoberts answer is probably more efficient and performant, but doesn't keep your interface the same.